# PHP error logging: Why Cyrillic characters get hex encoded in a log file and how to prevent it?

Tags: php, logging, cyrillic

I failed to find an answer. While trying to combat certain spam, I've noticed that all Cyrillic characters (e.g. Russian) are escaped and hex encoded in a PHP error log file.

I'm asking why, but common logic and preliminary reasoning suggests that this is most likely because server log files are in ASCII / ANSI format, and thus, information would be lost otherwise.

However, can we change log files into UTF-8 and prevent this from happening somehow? What config files do I need to change, if it is possible? Thx

Demo Code:

```
$s = 'Якс';
error_log($s); // outputs: \xd0\xaf\xd0\xba\xd1\x81
```

Comment: you can probably not use a multibyte encoding like UTF-8 and system logging. Documentation states that error_log isn't binary safe.

Comment: I guess the feature you want is only available for syslog: https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log